# Why couldn't Kakashi pass through things?

Tags: naruto

After Kakashi studied Tobi's movements during the Fourth Great Ninja War, he realized that his ability to teleport and pass through things is all one single jutsu, he even said it himself. The ability to pass through things is when Tobi sends a specific part of his body to the Kamui Time-Space. When he teleports, he takes his entire body with him. Even being said, Kakashi couldn't even pass through things until his fight with Kaguya Otsutsuki.

Knowing this, shouldn't Kakashi be able to pass through things as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Kakashi's inability to pass through things was mainly as a result of the bloodline limit restrictions of the Sharingan. This made the Sharingan use up a lot of his Chakra which limited the daily usage and  time duration in which Kakashi could use the Sharingan. Hence effectively preventing him from utilizing its true capabilities.

Like Fumikage Tokoyami already mentioned, the Sharingan is a Kekkai Genkai exclusive to the Uchiha and so compared to Obito who could freely use the Sharingan, Kakashi's use was fairly restricted. An interesting encounter where this was mentioned could be seen in Kakashi's battle against Itachi.

[image]

This "incompatibility" basically ensures that non-Uchihas are unable to truly unlock the hidden abilities of the Sharingan and hence acts as an impenetrable ceiling cap for anyone who isn't Uchiha.

Now back to the question, Obito's "pass through" ability is a pretty advanced application of the Kamui which seems to require less Chakra as its only shifts specific sections of his body to the Kamui dimesion. Nevertheless, the precision, accuracy and timing involved would require a great deal of training and understanding of Kamui that Kakashi could never  attain given his limited access to the Sharingan.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the two eyes of Obito performs two different actions. The right eye performs the space-time ninjutsu or the teleportation jutsu for the user only (so it a short range version of kamui). The left eye performs the teleportation jutsu for the enemy that is targeted i.e. the user looks at the target and concentrates so that the target is transported to the space-time dimension (so it is a long range version of Kamui). Kakashi has the left eye, so he can perform the long version of Kamui while Obito performs the short version of Kamui.

Even if Kakashi got the right eye, he couldn't be able to perform such a chakra-inducing jutsu because he is not an Uchiha. Note that Kamui is the speciality of Obito's Mangekyo Sharingan (which is [Kekkei Genkai](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kekkei_Genkai) exclusively for Uchiha clansmen only). So, using Kamui demands a great deal of chakra for him to perform. It takes him an extended period of time to gather enough chakra to use it, and once he does he cannot use it again. Even if he does, it won't be as effective as he would have wanted. Also, repeated use of Mangekyo Sharingan's abilities can damages user's vision, eventually reaching the point where it causes the eyes to bleed. For Kakashi, it would be very, very painful.

Comment: If the two eyes perform two different jutsu, how could he teleport and pass through things with only one eye?

Comment: Who is he? Obito or Kakashi? Read again. Right eye performs teleportation of the wielder. Left eye performs teleportation of the enemy to which it is targeted. Obito has right eye so he can teleport himself. Kakashi has the left eye, so he can teleport his enemy (but not himself).

Comment: By he I mean Kakashi. Obito is seen able to teleport, pass through things, and teleport other objects/people with one eye. Why can't Kakashi do the same? And if Kakashi can only teleport others, how would he escape Obito's dimension? (When Kurama threw him)

Comment: Because he has the left eye. Left eye performs long range kamui.

Comment: But you said that he can only teleport focused things besides himself? This is confusing me lol

Comment: "Kakashi has the left eye, so he can teleport his enemy (but not himself)"

Comment: Right eye performs wielders teleportation at will. Which makes sense for Obito to pass through things and teleport himself. But if left eye teleports others, Obito shouldn't be able to.